# find the chance to throw a dice for exactly $5$ times

Tags: probability

We toss a fair die with six faces $(1-6)$ until we get number $6$ exactly $3$ times.

What is the probability to toss the die exactly $5$ times?

I thought I just take the chance for getting $6$ which is $\frac{1}{6}$

Then putting in the binomial formula but I don't think it's that simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This event can be described as: among the first $4$ throws there are exactly $2$ numbers $6$ and the $5$-th throw is a number $6$.

Probability: $$\binom{4}{2}\left(\frac16\right)^2\left(\frac56\right)^2\times\frac16$$

Comment: Can you explain why it can describe like that?

Comment: If you are ready after exactly $5$ throws ($3$ sixes are thrown then) then of course you are not ready after $4$ throws (less than $3$ sixes are thrown then). So at the $5$-th throw you get the third six. Apparently after $4$ throws you allready had exactly two sixes.

Answer (score 0):

You have a sequence of $5$ values between $1-6$:

- $\color{red}{\text{Choose the last place and put $6$ in it}}$
- $\color{green}{\text{Choose $2$ out of the remaining $4$ places and put $6$ in each one of them}}$
- $\color{blue}{\text{Choose the remaining $2$ places and put a value between $1-5$ in each one of them}}$

The number of such sequences is $\color{red}{1}\cdot\color{green}{\binom42}\cdot\color{blue}{5^2}=150$.

The total number of sequence is $6^5=7776$, hence the probability is $\frac{150}{7776}$.